# how to find string in laravel blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I check data using something like strpos

## data->url = www.youtube.come/12345

```
@if($data->url != 'youtube' )

@endif

updated  how can i put this in my balde temp

preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+|(?<=/videos/)[^&^/\n]+#", $line['YOUTUBE'], $matches);

        $videoId = $matches[0];

        if(substr_count($line['YOUTUBE'], "facebook.com") > 0){
          print "<div class=\"fb-video\" data-href=\"{$line['YOUTUBE']}\" data-allowfullscreen=\"true\" data-width=\"600\"></div>";
        }else{
          print "<iframe width=\"600\" height=\"350\" frameborder=\"0\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{$videoId}?autoplay=1\"></iframe>";
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using strpos @if(strpos($data->url, 'youtube') ===false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any php function within blade too... see example below:

```
 @if (strpos($data->url, 'youtube') !== false) {
   echo 'true';
 @endif
```

Update: In some situations, it's useful to embed PHP code into your views. You can use the Blade @php directive to execute a block of plain PHP within your template:

```
@php
//
@endphp
```

While Blade provides this feature, using it frequently may be a signal that you have too much logic embedded within your template.
Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#php
Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: thnk you sirrrr

Comment: So is my answer :)

Comment: And please don't call me (or anyone) sir.. its weird  :D
Everyone here is learning, some are new and some are old, this is the only difference.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) (or their case insensitive variants when appropriate) but also you can use [Laravel's `str_contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-contains) function which is basically using `strpos()` PHP inbuilt method:

```
$contains = str_contains($line['YOUTUBE'], "facebook.com");
```